# Incrementing a string

Tags: java

How do I take an input and increment each letter by one e.g "ABC" to "BCD" in Java. 
I have attempted below to try and change the string to an int and then increase the value by 1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class w7q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String str ="";
        int A = 0;

        System.out.println ("Enter String");

        str = in.nextLine(); 

         int num = Integer.parseInt(str);

        num= num +1;


        System.out.println(str);
    }


    }
```

Comment: What happens if the letters are not consecutive, such as "ADT"? What happens if one of the letters is "Z"?

Comment: I guess you'd get some random ASCII garbage. Sounds like a homework question tbh, but no clue who'd do homework on Christmas.

Comment: @Arkanon Wouldn't the first one just produce `"BEU"`?  I didn't see anything ambiguous about that part of the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Loop over every `char` in the `String`, add one to the `char` and cast it back to a `char` append that to a `StringBuilder`. Something like,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter String");
String str = in.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append((char) (ch + 1));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Of course, if you want to handle wrap-around you could do something like

```
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    char o = ((char) (ch + 1));
    if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        if (o > '9') {
            o = '0';
        }
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
        if (o > 'z') {
            o = 'a';
        }
    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
        if (o > 'Z') {
            o = 'A';
        }
    }
    sb.append(o);
}
```